# How to generate auto number with unique values

Tags: php

Hello guys i have a table with **two primary keys** one is **ID** which is taking its

value from AUTO_NUMBER started from 10000 and go on.

The second field is **ImageID** which is primary key + unique Index means can not accept duplicate

but for this one i m using hidden fields of HTML but in value i m using the **rand()** function.

In here the problem is its generating duplicate numbers, I need unique values cause the Image

Field will not accept duplicate.

which function i should use to generate unique numbers.

Here is the hidden field codes:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ImageID" id="ImageID" value="<?php echo rand(1000,9999999999); ?>" />
```

Comment: Does ImageID need to be an integer?

Comment: What's the difference between `ID` and `ImageID`? Is it redundant?

Comment: yes it must be integer but not important from where and when start and how much be, but must be unique

Comment: @Wesley Murch: ID is the Id of table and ImageID is the ID by which i can retrieve images from Image table.

Comment: You already have `ID` which is guaranteed to be unique, what is the point of `ImageID`? Just to hide the real `ID`? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

The current unix timestamp is always going to be unique. You can also get it in microseconds for extra precision.

[microtime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php)

To prevent any possible collisions from entries being added at precisely the same microsecond (seems unlikely), you can append a random number to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use uniqid() . uniqid() function generates a unique ID based on the microtime (current time in microseconds). or you also use time().

Comment: can i specify number for it like rand() function

Comment: no you can't specify numbers like rand. But you can make a function and concatenate some other value to make it large or more unique.

Comment: its already 13 characters no need of making it large what about making it less cause i don't want to make my table heavy

Comment: so you can use time function it returns current unix timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try this:

```
<?php
$imageId = range(1000, 10000);
shuffle($imageId);
?>

<!-- you can use loop -->
<input type="hidden" name="ImageID" id="ImageID" value="<?php echo $imageId[0]; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="ImageID" id="ImageID" value="<?php echo $imageId[1]; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="ImageID" id="ImageID" value="<?php echo $imageId[2]; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="ImageID" id="ImageID" value="<?php echo $imageId[3]; ?>" />
```

Comment: how it will shuffle, possible or duplicate or not ?

Comment: This function shuffles (randomizes the order of the elements in) an array.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="hidden" name="ImageID" id="ImageID" value="<?php echo time(); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="ImageID" id="ImageID" value="<?php echo time(); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="ImageID" id="ImageID" value="<?php echo time(); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="ImageID" id="ImageID" value="<?php echo time(); ?>" />
```

Comment: Arayan: dear the value is not changing when the page is refereshing.

Comment: what you need exactly.

Comment: by refereshing the page values must be change

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="ImageID" id="ImageID" value="<?php echo md5(uniqid().time()) ?>" />

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="ImageID" id="ImageID" value="<?php echo uniqid() ?>" />

Comment: try this this is allso produce unique id each time and if you able to increase size in db so use the above one.

Comment: only uniqid() is taking 13 characters if i have 30 records per day u dont think it will make it heavy ?

Comment: Only one option remaining is that you check the last unique id that was on db and increment that by 1 and make id imageid.

Comment: At the start up of the page call query for it and increment by 1 and make that imageid.

Comment: Sorry i did not get you

Comment: "SELECT id FROM tablename ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1" this query you run at top of the page it will return the last id you add 1 in that and make it the new imageid.